# Why doesn't login provide me a session_id()?

Tags: php, session, pdo, authentication

I'm building a simple login system.
Registration is working with password_default:

[image]

So, now the login. This is my login class:

```
<?php
include("../Controllers/DatabaseController.php");

class LoginModel extends DatabaseController
{

protected $dbconn;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbconn = DatabaseController::instance();
}

public function Login()
{

    $db = $this->dbconn->pdo;

    try {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $passwordAttempt = $_POST['user_password'];

        //Retrieve the user account information for the given username.
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        //Bind value.
        $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);

        //Execute.
        $stmt->execute();

        //Fetch row.
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //If $row is FALSE.
        if ($user === false) {
            //Could not find a user with that username!
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("username not found!");
                window.location.href = "../Views/login.php";
            </script>
            <?php
        } else {

            //User account found. Check to see if the given password matches the
            //password hash that we stored in our users table..
            $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt, $user['user_password']);

            //If $validPassword is TRUE, the login has been successful.
            if ($validPassword) {

                //Provide the user with a login session.
                $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

                //Redirect to our protected page, which we called home, to see if we are provided a session.php
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("You're logged in!");
                    window.location.href = "../index.php";
                </script>
                <?php
                header('Location: home.php');
                exit;
            } else {
                //$validPassword was FALSE. Passwords do not match.
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Password is incorrect!");
                    window.location.href = "../Views/login.php";
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}
```

Now I know, it isn't proper OOP, but I'm learning.

When I press login, passwords do match:

[image]

But when redirecting to home.php, it seems the log in didn't provide me with a session_id...

[image]

Home.php:

```
<?php
/**
* Start the session.
*/
session_start();
/**
* Check if the user is logged in.
*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']) || !isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
//User not logged in. Redirect them back to the login.php page.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You're not logged in!" );
</script>
<?php
exit;
}
/**
* Print out something that only logged in users can see.
*/

echo 'Congratulations! You are logged in!';
```

I hope somebody has a solution, because I don't see one unfortunately.

For completion my partial login.php:

```
<?php
include "../Models/LoginModel.php";

$login = new LoginModel();
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$login->Login();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<title>Title</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style-registration.css">


</head>
<body>
<?php
include 'header.php';
?>
<div class="signup-form">
<form action="" method="post">
```

And my partial header.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
<title>Scores Website</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style-index.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl bg-light">
```

Comment: Did you start a session in the login page?

Comment: Yes, I have included with every page (also login.php) a header.php which has a session_start().

Comment: Try to have session_start(); very first line after opening php tag... As I see you have it in header that is included after the login model...

Comment: Am i wrong or you really got 2 Doctype / Head etc... ? Since login has one and after you include header which has one too

Comment: @PHPnoob ,oops, yes I have. Corrected it, thnx.

Comment: @PHPnoob , but header uses a different style-sheet...

Comment: You must have a single header per page. If you need different CSS files depending on the situation, write a function to display the header and call them as parameter.

Comment: Thnx @VipinKumarSoni! It's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to end with that kind of structure :

```
<?php 
    include "../Models/LoginModel.php";

    session_start(); 

    if ($_POST) {
        //execute login method
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    //set title, meta, call needed css files
</head>
<body>
    //your form etc...
    //end with javascript calls
</body>
</html>
```

In this order everything should works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did like @vipin-kumar-soni said above. First session_start(), then include Model. If you change that in your answer above, I'll can click it to accept your answer.

Comment: Did you try mine ? Guess it is working aswell else i'll edit ofc

Comment: Because the session needs to be started before using it (seems logic) and the first time you use it is when you call your login function so it's no matter whether you set includes before or after the session_start ()

Comment: I didn't try it, because I have to change some 10 webpages again, but if you say it doesn't matter, I'll accept your answer too.